# How to make Listview.OnItemClick fier thogerther with Button.OnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my `ListView` I have rows containing buttons. When the button is pressed, I want to first have the `ListView`s `OnitemClickListener` react, followed by the Buttons listener. So I want both events to happen.

**Note:** 
I don't want to have an independent event for a situation where the user clicks on a button or area outside of a button which can be achieved with `android:descendantFocusability` or `android:focusable="false"`.

Answer (score -1):

Do a regular OnClickListener to the button, with the ID of the button.